# Grunt (Magento 2) - Why do I have to force my commands?

Tags: magento2, grunt, wamp, local

I've just installed grunt for the first time however I cannot run any commands in cmd wihtout using --force.

My error is:

> C:\wamp64\www\New_Mage2>grunt watch
>
> jit-grunt: Plugin for the "watch" task not found. If you have
>   installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping. See
>   https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings
>
> Warning: Task "watch" failed. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.
>
> Execution Time (2018-08-31 12:48:33 UTC+1) loading tasks  293ms 
>   ███████████████████████████████████████████████
>
> ████████████████████████████████████████ 100% Total 294ms

Any help is much appreciated.